# ansible order results in a table / transpose

Tags: ansible

the following produces information for about 60 certificates but I need to transpose it if possible in like a table with headers 'common_name','serial_number','ca','type','expiry_time','scope' - is that possible?

```
---
- name: NetApp Certificate Expiry Reporting
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  collections:
    - netapp.ontap

  vars:
    pp_ontap_clusters:
      - cls1
      - cls2
      - cls3
      - cls4
      - cls5
      - cls6
      - cls7

  tasks:
  - name: run ONTAP gather facts for certificate info with specified fields
    netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info:
      hostname: "{{ item }}"
      username: "{{ lookup('env', 'ontap_admin_usr') }}"
      password: "{{ lookup('env', 'ontap_admin_pwd') }}"
      use_rest: always
      https: true
      validate_certs: false
      gather_subset:
        - security/certificates
      fields:
        - 'common_name'
        - 'serial_number'
        - 'ca'
        - 'type'
        - 'expiry_time'
        - 'scope'
      parameters:
        type: server
    loop: "{{ pp_ontap_clusters }}"
```

this is the output for a single certificate as an example

```
17:28:44     "item": "cls1",
17:28:44     "ontap_info": {
17:28:44         "security/certificates": {
17:28:44             "_links": {
17:28:44                 "self": {
17:28:44                     "href": "/api/security/certificates?max_records=1024&fields=common_name%2Cserial_number%2Cca%2Ctype%2Cexpiry_time%2Cscope&type=server"
17:28:44                 }
17:28:44             },
17:28:44             "num_records": 4,
17:28:44             "records": [
17:28:44                 {
17:28:44                     "_links": {
17:28:44                         "self": {
17:28:44                             "href": "/api/security/certificates/dce3b162-1c4c-11ee-b505-00a098f2ea72"
17:28:44                         }
17:28:44                     },
17:28:44                     "ca": "cls11113",
17:28:44                     "common_name": "cls11113",
17:28:44                     "expiry_time": "2024-07-05T23:31:34+01:00",
17:28:44                     "name": "cls11113_176F67F694B6B7ED",
17:28:44                     "scope": "svm",
17:28:44                     "serial_number": "176F67F694B6B7ED",
17:28:44                     "type": "server",
17:28:44                     "uuid": "dce3b162-1c4c-11ee-b505-00a098f2ea72"
17:28:44                 },
```

Comment: You can produce pretty much whatever sort of report you want use the [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the fields into a list

```yaml
  pp_ontap_fields: [common_name, serial_number, ca, type, expiry_time, scope]
```

Then, given the below data for testing

```yaml
    data:
      results:
        - item: cls1
          ontap_info:
            security/certificates:
              _links:
                self:
                  href: /api/security/certificates?max_records=1024&fields=common_name%2Cserial_number  type%2Cexpiry_time%2Cscope&type=server
              num_records: 4
              records:
              - _links:
                  self:
                    href: /api/security/certificates/dce3b162-1c4c-11ee-b505-00a098f2ea72
                ca: cls11113
                common_name: cls11113
                expiry_time: '2024-07-05T23:31:34+01:00'
                name: cls11113_176F67F694B6B7ED
                scope: svm
                serial_number: 176F67F694B6B7ED
                type: server
                uuid: dce3b162-1c4c-11ee-b505-00a098f2ea72
```

Create a dictionary

```yaml
  certs: "{{ dict(data.results|json_query(certs_query)) }}"
  certs_query: '[].[item, ontap_info."security/certificates".records]'
```

gives

```yaml
  certs:
    cls1:
    - _links:
        self:
          href: /api/security/certificates/dce3b162-1c4c-11ee-b505-00a098f2ea72
      ca: cls11113
      common_name: cls11113
      expiry_time: '2024-07-05T23:31:34+01:00'
      name: cls11113_176F67F694B6B7ED
      scope: svm
      serial_number: 176F67F694B6B7ED
      type: server
      uuid: dce3b162-1c4c-11ee-b505-00a098f2ea72
```

Use the dictionary to write all certificates into a single file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/certs.csv
        content: |
          {{ pp_ontap_fields|join(';') }}
          {% for cluster,certs in certs.items() %}
          {% for cert in certs %}
          {{ pp_ontap_fields|map('extract', cert)|join(';') }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/certs.csv 
common_name;serial_number;ca;type;expiry_time;scope
cls11113;176F67F694B6B7ED;cls11113;server;2024-07-05T23:31:34+01:00;svm
```

, or write certificates to files by clusters

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/certs-{{ item.key }}.csv"
        content: |
          {{ pp_ontap_fields|join(';') }}
          {% for cert in item.value %}
          {{ pp_ontap_fields|map('extract', cert)|join(';') }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ certs|dict2items }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    pp_ontap_fields: [common_name, serial_number, ca, type, expiry_time, scope]
    
    data:
      results:
        - item: cls1
          ontap_info:
            security/certificates:
              _links:
                self:
                  href: /api/security/certificates?max_records=1024&fields=common_name%2Cserial_number  type%2Cexpiry_time%2Cscope&type=server
              num_records: 4
              records:
              - _links:
                  self:
                    href: /api/security/certificates/dce3b162-1c4c-11ee-b505-00a098f2ea72
                ca: cls11113
                common_name: cls11113
                expiry_time: '2024-07-05T23:31:34+01:00'
                name: cls11113_176F67F694B6B7ED
                scope: svm
                serial_number: 176F67F694B6B7ED
                type: server
                uuid: dce3b162-1c4c-11ee-b505-00a098f2ea72

    certs: "{{ dict(data.results|json_query(certs_query)) }}"
    certs_query: '[].[item, ontap_info."security/certificates".records]'
                
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: certs

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/certs.csv
        content: |
          {{ pp_ontap_fields|join(';') }}
          {% for cluster,certs in certs.items() %}
          {% for cert in certs %}
          {{ pp_ontap_fields|map('extract', cert)|join(';') }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}

    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/certs-{{ item.key }}.csv"
        content: |
          {{ pp_ontap_fields|join(';') }}
          {% for cert in item.value %}
          {{ pp_ontap_fields|map('extract', cert)|join(';') }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ certs|dict2items }}"
```